# Android Kotlin: Decode base64 image string as Image

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I'm trying to decode a base64 image to set the image into an imageview.

```
var decodedString: ByteArray = Base64.decode(asset?.image, Base64.DEFAULT)
var decodedByte: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size);
assetImg.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory.decodeByte…g, 0,
>   decodedString.size) must not be null

Comment: please check your base64 strings. is it valid?

Comment: @Happy Singh Yes, it's valid

Comment: I need to see how your string is encoded. because DEFAULT can cause null because of your decode type. it can be URL_SAFE